# Java Scanner/Input Help (input mismatch exception)

Tags: java

atm program. when you press a number it redirects you to an option. ex. 2 = deposit. it asks for the amount to withdraw or to press 'b' to go to the main menu. if you input the amount to deposit it works fine. if you press 'b' to get to the main menu, it will not work and send an input mismatch exception

```
static double balance = 0.0;
public static void deposit(double amount)
{
    balance = balance + amount;
}

public static void withdraw(double amount)
{
    balance = balance - amount;
}


private static void transaction()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the ATM");
    System.out.println("1 for balance\n2 for deposit\n3 for withdraw");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);

        transaction();
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter the amount or 'b' to go back");
        if (input.nextLine() == "b")
        {
        transaction();
        }
        else 
        {
        deposit(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Success!");
        transaction();
        }***
    case 3:
        if (balance >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Your balance is negative!");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount");
        withdraw(input.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Success!");
        transaction();
        }
    default:
        System.out.println("Enter a valid option");
        transaction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.quals()` instead of `==` for equality checking -

> `input.nextLine().equals("b")`

#### Bonus suggestion:

You should not take input directly inside `if()` rather take the user input as `String` first. Then check if its `b` otherwise convert it to `double` and deposit it!

```
String userInput = input.next();

if (userInput.equals("b")) {
    transaction();
} else {
    try {
        double depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        deposit(depositAmount);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: when I go into the withdraw or deposit menu, there is an option to press 'b' to go back to all the options. when i press b, i get an error.

Comment: Based on your given code sample, there is no option for user to press "b" in `case 3` which is withdraw. For `case 2` user can give both input - *amount* or *b*. And this case well handled in my given answer.  Also there is a logical error at `case 3`. It should be `balance <= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

since user some time can enter white space before or after character it is always good to have trim for user inputs.
I would suggest even to make a null check before entering the condition since else case could even work for null input.
It is always good coding practice to use equals with field that is a constant as first argument in order to avoid NullPointerException.
 import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Test {

    static double balance = 0.0;
    public static void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public static void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }


    private static void transaction()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the ATM");
        System.out.println("1 for balance\n2 for deposit\n3 for withdraw");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Your balance is " + balance);

            transaction();
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter the amount or 'b' to go back");
            String temp = input.nextLine().trim();
            if(!temp.isEmpty()) {
                if ("b".equals(temp))   // since user some time can enter white space before or after character                                        // I would suggest even to make a null check before entering box.
                { 
                transaction();
                }
                else 
                {
                deposit(input.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Success!");
                transaction();
                }
            }
        case 3:
            if (balance >= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Your balance is negative!");
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount");
            withdraw(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Success!");
            transaction();
            }
        default:
            System.out.println("Enter a valid option");
            transaction();
        }
    }


}
```

Hope this was helpful.